# Prove: If $a \mid b$ and $a>0$ , then $(a,b) = a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've only written that $b=an$ where $n$ is some integer and if $(a,b)= a$, then $a \mid a$ and $a \mid b$.

I don't quite know what to do and am hoping someone could walk me through this.

Comment: You're really close. What does it mean that $a|b$?

Comment: $(a,an)=a\cdot (1,n)=a\cdot 1=a$.

Comment: So $a$ is a common divisor. Could something greater than $a$ be a common divisor? It would have to divide $a$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll write an explanation based just on the definitions.

To show that $a$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$, you need to show the following:

- $a\mid b$ and $a\mid a$
- $a$ is the greatest integer that divides both $a$ and $b$.

You are given that $b\mid a$ and any integer divides itself (because $k=1\cdot k$ for any $k\in\Bbb Z$), so the first condition is met.

Note that $-a$ also divides both $a$ and $b$, because $a=-1\cdot a$ and $b=a\cdot (-n)$, for the $n$ in your attempt.

Hence, the gcd could be either $a$ or $-a$. Here's where you use the hypothesis that $a>0$:
$$a>0\implies 0>-a \implies a>-a$$

You don't need to worry about any other divisor $c$ different from $a$ and $-a$, because if $c\mid a$ and $c\mid b$, you immediately have $c\mid a$.

Thus, $a$ is indeed the greatest integer that divides both $a$ and $b$.